# Is there a way to determine a page title with a class instead of using Laravel templates @yield and @content?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Specifically, I want one class, or method, to be taking care of what's going to be in my `<title>` tag in app.blade.php file (the file included on every page).

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with laravel sessions, firstly you can add a session variable lets say on login like this

```
Session::put('title', $value);
```

Now you can change this every time you switch the page via controller, just add this to every request and change the title as you please, and finally in your blades you can just do this

```
<title>{{ Session::get('title') ?? 'Login' }}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Generally, I use this:
In my `app.blade.php`

```
<title> {{ $title ? $title.' - ' ? '' }} website-name </title>
```

And in the `controller files` I used to return the `$data` array instead of the compact method:

```
$data['title'] = 'My title';

return view('view.name', $data);
```

This will automatically consider the title if you add it to your controller else it will display the website name. No need to add the "<title>" tag in every blade file.

---

**Option 2:**

Make `__construct` method in the controller class file.

```
public function __construct( Request $request )
{
    $route_basename      = basename(URL::current());
    $this->data['title'] = \Str::title(str_replace('-', ' ', $route_basename));
}
```

`Note: if you are using _ as the separation in the route then replace '-' with '_' in the str_replace() function`.

The above code will convert your Last route segment in to the title. `Example: you have admin/categories` then you got the `Categories` as the title.

Now you need to return `$this->data` in the view method.

```
public function index()
{
    // If you want to send any other data in the index view.
    $this->data['categories'] = Categories::all();  // optional

    return view('admin.categories.index', $this->data);
}
```

If you are go for the 2nd option then you don't need to declare `$data['title']` in every method.

But in some cases we have `id` as the last route segment or any other thing that not belongs to the title at that time just overwrite the `$this->data['title']` in that `method or function`.

Comment: Seriously? You do that in every single controller and method? I'd like to somehow avoid doing that and instead, using a single class or a method, that determines what title to output, with route name as an input. Hmm, I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Hey! I add 2nd option in my answer. Could you please check that one?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using and @section('title') in every blade where I need to specify the title.